# Git bash keeps asking for ssh passphrase when pushing to Bitbucket repo

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, git-bash

I've set up a new project on Bitbucket (private repo) and have followed their instructions ([Set up an SSH key](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html)) to create an SSH key for when working with Bitbucket in my new Android Studio project. Everything is set up correctly to the best of my knowledge and yet every time I wish to push/fetch, Android Studio keeps asking for my passphrase.

Just to elaborate, I've followed these steps:

1. Set up a new private repo in Bitbucket
2. Set up the SSH key
3. Created a new Android Studio project
4. Set up Version Control in Android Studio and added files to the staging area and committed these using the GUI interface, followed by defining the remote URL as the SSH URL specified in the repo, at git@bitbucket.org:myusername/myreponame. This step works fine without prompting for my passphrase.
5. Attempt to add/commit/push changes via the embedded git bash terminal - keeps asking for the passphrase.

To clarify, I've also checked the config file for Android Studio and it is using the correct SSH URL. Finally, I've scoured many sources online for a solution and have done the obvious so far, including restarting Android Studio and my PC (Windows), yet the problem persists.

Comment: What is the output of running `git remote -v` and `ssh -T git@bitbucket.org` on git bash?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - I've tried the commands you specified and I do get the correct fetch/push URL for my repo for the first command (SSH). The second command allows me to enter my passphrase (once again), followed by logging me in, yet the same issue is still evident in Android Studio requiring me to enter my passphrase in the terminal for fetch/push commands. I've currently got the support team at Bitbucket looking into this now as I've exhausted all options.

Comment: By "passphrase" do you mean the Bitbucket account password or the ssh key passphrase? Can you still post the output of the commands? I think I know what the problem is.

Comment: The 'passphrase' being the SSH key passphrase. The first command (git remote -v) returns the following: "origin git@bitbucket.org:myusername/myreponame.git (fetch) origin git@bitbucket.org:myusername/myreponame (push)". The second command (ssh -T git@bitbucket.org) returns "Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/Richard/.ssh/id_rsa':
logged in as myusername.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled."

Comment: What is the output of these in the terminal? `uname -a` `$SHELL --version`

Comment: The command 'uname -a' doesn't execute, yet '$SHELL --version' using Git Bash executes and returns the following: "GNU bash, version 4.4.19(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>"

Comment: "The command 'uname -a' doesn't execute" That's weird, it works on my git bash and the bash version is the same.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177518/discussion-between-kelvin-and-richard-ansell).

Answer (score 4):

Please run this command where ~/.ssh is the path for your public key

```
ssh-add -K ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Comment: I did already try this earlier on and it simply states it's an 'unknown option -- k', followed by a list of available options

Comment: Please try without -k     "ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa"

Comment: I've just tried the first command again without the capital 'k' and it states the identity has been added, yet the same issue still remains. Also, I've tried your second suggestion before as per Bitbucket's instructions I stated I have already followed

Comment: This solution worked for me. For the new people, I would like to say please change your file name after `~/.ssh` like `/.ssh/YOUR FILE NAME WHERE YOU ARE FACING PROBLEM`

Answer (score 2):

You need an [ssh-agent](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-agent). That's what [caches the passphrase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72558/301259).

Try the following on git bash:

```sh
eval $(ssh-agent)

# Change this if needed
key='~/.ssh/id_rsa'

ssh-add $key
```

See also:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12195/how-to-avoid-being-asked-passphrase-each-time-i-push-to-bitbucket

Comment: Thanks for your support with this Kelvin, yet I've already tried your suggestion as part of Bitbucket's step-by-step guide for adding an SSH key in the link in my original post with no luck so far unfortunately (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html#SetupanSSHkey-Step2.Addthekeytothessh-agent)

Comment: You're welcome. That's weird, is Android Studio using the git bash that comes with GFW (I assume you installed it separately) or does it bundle its own git bash?

Comment: I did install Git separately yet I'd assume saving the key as per the instructions by Bitbucket would've still taken effect in the terminal. However, I have just changed the option in Android Studio to use Git Bash when selecting the terminal that does allow it to work, yet I'd prefer using the terminal as it is.